# Erratic cursor movement and clicks on Dell laptop with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, mouse

I recently removed Windows from my laptop and installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. After a short while my cursor would move randomly and laptop would trigger left clicks.

I initially though my machine got hacked, so I disabled the internet but it obviously didn't work. STUPID!

I found similar problems by other users but it mostly went away by restarting the touchpad input driver.

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
```

This didn't solve anything either.

What I noticed later was that the erratic movement and click only trigger whenever I pressed Ctrl or Shift keys on the keyboard. This led me to think that something is not wired probably within the keyboard. The keyboard also has an in-built tracking stick with its own mouse buttons. So I went ahead and disabled the tracking stick.

```
xinput set-prop "<track stick name>" "Device Enabled" 0
```

This solved my problem and I haven't observed it again.

Is there any other explanation to this? This never happened on Windows. Despite this Ubuntu wins in all other requirements from me.

Comment: I have came across another post from Dell that describes a similar problem and a possible fix.
https://www.dell.com/support/article/de-de/sln308258/precision-xps-ubuntu-fix-f%C3%BCr-allgemeines-touchpad-mausproblem?lang=de

Comment: The command sudo modprobe -r psmouse worked for me. It stopped my cursor. I have a Lenovo Thinkpad and Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems with an erratic mouse movement and keyboard clicks that basically made my laptop unusable.  I was on a Dell XPS 17 with Ubuntu 22.04 with all the latest patches.

I also found the article linked by Ravish above to the Dell support site.  However, it is for working on a really old version of Ubuntu.   It does give us a few hints on what we should do though.

First thing is to do an `xinput --list` command to see what kind of devices you have.  In my case, the pointer section should up like this (below I have my external keyboard and mouse attached from my docking station, but problem exists with or without the external devices plugged in):

```
$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Gaming Mouse G502                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Gaming Mouse G502 Keyboard       id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair Gaming K95 RGB PLATINUM Keyboard  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair Gaming K95 RGB PLATINUM Keyboard Mouse    id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN2097:00 04F3:2A16                     id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VEN_06CB:00 06CB:CE7E Mouse               id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VEN_06CB:00 06CB:CE7E Touchpad            id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 590A01 USB Storage Mouse                  id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=29   [slave  pointer  (2)]
 
<snip>
```

The Dell support article mentions disabling the duplicate device, though the device names in the article did not match my hardware above.   So, I just did some trial and error to find the problematic device.

You can temporarily disable a device using `xinput disable <device_id>` command to see if it fixes the issue.   For me, as soon as I disabled the ELAN2097 device, the erratic behavior stopped.   Since the ELAN2097 device had device id 18, I ran the following to disable it temporarily:

```
xinput disable 18
```

Now that we know which device is the one causing an issue, we can make it permanent by writing a xorg conf to disable the device.   I found it easiest to disable by the device usb id which you can find after the name of the device in the `xinput` output (eg. `04F3:2A16` for this case).  If the USB ID doesn't show up in the short list, you can use the `xinput list <device_id>` to see the full information for the device.

So to finish, create the xorg conf file, and then reboot your system to test to make sure the device is permanently disabled:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-disable-bad-touchpad-device.conf 

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable bad touchpad device"
        MatchUSBID "04F3:2A16"
        Option "Ignore" "true"
EndSection
```